# Cannot install drawnow

Tags: python, pip

`Could not import setuptools which is required to install from a source distribution.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 387, in setup_py
    import setuptools  # noqa
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    import setuptools.version
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\version.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from six.moves import urllib, map, filter
ImportError: cannot import name urllib`

how to solve this problem i already update pip

Comment: It is trying to `import urllib` that is not there in package you are trying to install, see dependency of package and install dependency first. than try again, else download the package again in other case.

Comment: Requires Python: >=2.6,!=3.0.*,!=3.1.*,!=3.2.*